# Error while Deploying SSIS package to SQL Server 2012 DB SSIS Catalog using SQL Server 2014 client

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to deply SSIS Package (ispac file) created in SQL 2012 Data Tools using SQL Server 2014
I have followed following steps

1. Opened SQL 2014
2. Connected to Datase Server (SQL Server 2012)
3. Created a folder under Integration Services Catalog/SSISDB
4. Double clicked on my ispac file and selected source as Ispac file and Destination as the folder created in step 2
5. The package was deployed successfully.
6. Configured the parameters properly

However when I Validated or tried to execute the package it gave me following errors.

[image]

When I tried to deploy it on SQL 2012 using SQL 2012 client instead of MS SQL 2014 it worked fine. I tried it by remotely logging into database server.

Is there any solution for it?
Do I have to login to server and perform the deployment. Can't I just do it from my Local machine?

Comment: If you've ascertained that the SQL 2014 client is the issue.... just install the SQL 2012 client locally

Answer (score 1):

Your log definitely shows that packages were upgraded to SSIS 2014 format - see message with **PackageFormatVersion 8**. When you deploy project with SSIS Deployment Wizard, which is invoked from SQL 2014 SSMS, the Project is converted implicitly. Recommendation - install SSMS from SQL 2012 and deploy from it. You might do it locally, not necessarily logging on to the server.